# Dynamically assigning and positioning DIV'S in java script

Tags: javascript, dom

I am having issues dynamically assigning JS to a div then modifying the div on the fly.

All code is attached un changed, i cant figure out for the life of me why its not behaving as intended, what should happen as you can see from the code is each widget should be positioned left then right, and so on down the page.

Div is created and assigned dynamic name, then code is placed inside div, then div position is modified. This should work?

```
  var i = 0;
    var howManyCharts = 4;
    var float = ["left","right"];
    var lastID = "chart" + i.toString();
    document.getElementById("chart").id = lastID;
    while (i < howManyCharts) {
        var div = document.createElement('div').id = "charts" + i.toString();
        div.innerHTML = chart("5","EURUSD");
        div.style.float = float[i % 2];
        i = i + 1;
    };
```

The logic is in the while loop.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#chart {
    position: static;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    width: 400px;
    float: left;
    float: top;
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>



<div id="chart">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d33t3vvu2t2yu5.cloudfront.net/tv.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var i = 0;
var howManyCharts = 4;
var float = ["left","right"];
var lastID = "chart" + i.toString();
document.getElementById("chart").id = lastID;
while (i < howManyCharts) {
    var div = document.createElement('div').id = "charts" + i.toString();
    div.innerHTML = chart("5","EURUSD");
    div.style.float = float[i % 2];
    i = i + 1;
};



function chart(interval, symbol){
    new TradingView.widget({
        "width": 400,
        "height": 400,
        "symbol": symbol,
        "interval": interval,
        "timezone": "Australia/Sydney",
        "theme": "Black",
        "style": "1",
        "locale": "en",
        "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
        "enable_publishing": false,
        "hide_top_toolbar": true,
        "allow_symbol_change": true,
        "save_image": false,
        "hideideas": true,
        "studies": [
            "RSI@tv-basicstudies"
        ]
    });
};
</script>
</div>
</body>
```

Entire code posted above
also here on fiddler: http://js.do/code/multichart

Comment: Can I suggest posting a plunker/jsfiddle/codepen to demo this? It seems simple enough.

Comment: http://js.do/code/multichart

Comment: I see mod has edited question, i cant see what was edited.
I spouse to simply add a dot and cross a T for i see nothing different at all, most amusing he didn't even bother to try respond to the topic just "edit" it so his name pops up and he gets a coin, no actual editing happened and no actual contribution to the topic...

Answer (score 1):

You have a logical error here:

```
 var div = document.createElement('div').id = "charts" + i.toString();
 div.innerHTML = chart("5","EURUSD");
```

That first line will assign *the id* to the variable `div`. I think what you want to do instead is

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = "charts" + i.toString();
div.innerHTML = chart("5","EURUSD");
```

Re the layout - I would suggest not using floats. They should be used more for allowing text to wrap around items, rather than general layout.

I suggest using a flex layout, like this.

```
div {
   margin: 5px;
   padding: 5px;
   border: solid 1px black; 
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.item {
   flex: 1 0 40%;  //cheap hack to account for margins
   height: 50px; 
}

<div class = "container"> 
   <div class = "item">1</div> 
   <div class = "item">2</div> 
   <div class = "item">3</div> 
   <div class = "item">4</div> 
</div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/i15GJhedGYTHbvM3z8sF?p=preview

Comment: The logical error didn't change anything. http://js.do/code/multichart2

Comment: I appreciate your CSS advice but as the original question was a JS problem can you replicate the fix using my code?